Facing Errors while installing Soroban CLI
this is what i get in terminal output:
C:\Users\admin> cargo install --locked soroban-cli

DEBUG:    1+  >>>> cargo install --locked soroban-cli
Updating crates.io index
Installing soroban-cli v20.3.4
Updating crates.io index
Updating crates.io index
Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.69
Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.12
Compiling serde v1.0.192
Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
Compiling thiserror v1.0.55
Compiling once_cell v1.19.0
Compiling windows_x86_64_msvc v0.52.0
Compiling memchr v2.7.1
Compiling itoa v1.0.10
Compiling quote v1.0.33
Compiling syn v2.0.39
Compiling windows-targets v0.52.0
Compiling windows-sys v0.52.0
Compiling version_check v0.9.4
Compiling typenum v1.17.0
Compiling smallvec v1.13.1
Compiling winapi v0.3.9
Compiling bytes v1.5.0
Compiling windows_x86_64_msvc v0.48.5
error[E0786]: found invalid metadata files for crate compiler_builtins which std depends on
|
= note: failed to mmap file '\?\C:\Users\admin.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\libcompiler_builtins-34df001b737926cd.rlib': The paging file is too small for this operation to complete. (os error 1455)
memory allocation of 2096640 bytes failed
error: cannot find macro println in this scope
--> C:\Users\admin.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\windows_x86_64_msvc-0.48.5\build.rs:9:5
|
9 |     println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", std::path::Path::new(&dir).join("lib").display());
|     ^^^^^^^
error[E0462]: found staticlib std instead of rlib or dylib
--> C:\Users\admin.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\windows_x86_64_msvc-0.48.5\build.rs:2:18
|
2 |     let target = std::env::var("TARGET").unwrap();
|                  ^^^
|
= note: the following crate versions were found:
crate std: C:\Users\admin.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\std-49e3d1aefc00cc02.dll.lib
= help: please recompile that crate using --crate-type lib
error[E0462]: found staticlib std instead of rlib or dylib
--> C:\Users\admin.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\windows_x86_64_msvc-0.48.5\build.rs:7:15
|
7 |     let dir = std::env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap();
|               ^^^
|
= note: the following crate versions were found:
crate std: C:\Users\admin.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\std-49e3d1aefc00cc02.dll.lib
= help: please recompile that crate using --crate-type lib
error: #[panic_handler] function required, but not found
error: unwinding panics are not supported without std
|
= help: using nightly cargo, use -Zbuild-std with panic="abort" to avoid unwinding
= note: since the core library is usually precompiled with panic="unwind", rebuilding your crate with panic="abort" may not be enough to fix the problem
error: requires sized lang_item
Some errors have detailed explanations: E0462, E0786.
For more information about an error, try rustc --explain E0462.
error: could not compile windows_x86_64_msvc (build script) due to 7 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
memory allocation of 1300736 bytes failed
error: could not compile windows-sys (lib)
Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: C:\Users\admin\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin\rustc.exe --crate-name windows_sys --edition=2021 C:\Users\admin\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\windows-sys-0.52.0\src\lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=145 --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg "feature=\"Win32\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_Foundation\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_NetworkManagement\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_NetworkManagement_IpHelper\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_Networking\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_Networking_WinSock\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_Security\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_Security_Authentication\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_Security_Authentication_Identity\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_Security_Authorization\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_Security_Credentials\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_Security_Cryptography\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_Storage\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_Storage_FileSystem\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_System\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_System_Com\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_System_Console\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_System_Diagnostics\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_System_Diagnostics_Debug\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_System_Memory\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_System_Threading\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_UI\"" --cfg "feature=\"Win32_UI_Shell\"" --cfg "feature=\"default\"" -C metadata=71e6f15bfb9843c9 -C extra-filename=-71e6f15bfb9843c9 --out-dir C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-install0pJ2NA\release\deps -L dependency=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-install0pJ2NA\release\deps --extern windows_targets=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-install0pJ2NA\release\deps\libwindows_targets-8b73114dfc772279.rmeta --cap-lints allow -L native=C:\Users\admin\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\windows_x86_64_msvc-0.52.0\lib (exit code: 0xc0000409, STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN)
error: could not compile winapi (lib)
Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: C:\Users\admin\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin\rustc.exe --crate-name winapi --edition=2015 C:\Users\admin\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\winapi-0.3.9\src\lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=145 --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg "feature=\"consoleapi\"" --cfg "feature=\"errhandlingapi\"" --cfg "feature=\"fileapi\"" --cfg "feature=\"handleapi\"" --cfg "feature=\"knownfolders\"" --cfg "feature=\"minwindef\"" --cfg "feature=\"objbase\"" --cfg "feature=\"processenv\"" --cfg "feature=\"shlobj\"" --cfg "feature=\"std\"" --cfg "feature=\"sysinfoapi\"" --cfg "feature=\"winbase\"" --cfg "feature=\"wincon\"" --cfg "feature=\"winerror\"" --cfg "feature=\"winnt\"" --cfg "feature=\"winsock2\"" -C metadata=ba0f128c5e3ee35f -C extra-filename=-ba0f128c5e3ee35f --out-dir C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-install0pJ2NA\release\deps -L dependency=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-install0pJ2NA\release\deps --cap-lints allow -l dylib=advapi32 -l dylib=cfgmgr32 -l dylib=gdi32 -l dylib=kernel32 -l dylib=msimg32 -l dylib=ole32 -l dylib=opengl32 -l dylib=shell32 -l dylib=user32 -l dylib=winspool -l dylib=ws2_32 --cfg "feature=\"cfg\"" --cfg "feature=\"oaidl\"" --cfg "feature=\"rpcdce\"" --cfg "feature=\"vadefs\"" --cfg "feature=\"libloaderapi\"" --cfg "feature=\"shtypes\"" --cfg "feature=\"devpropdef\"" --cfg "feature=\"wtypesbase\"" --cfg "feature=\"ws2def\"" --cfg "feature=\"minwinbase\"" --cfg "feature=\"unknwnbase\"" --cfg "feature=\"wtypes\"" --cfg "feature=\"wingdi\"" --cfg "feature=\"excpt\"" --cfg "feature=\"combaseapi\"" --cfg  "feature=\"objidl\"" --cfg "feature=\"processthreadsapi\"" --cfg "feature=\"rpcndr\"" --cfg "feature=\"ntdef\"" --cfg "feature=\"vcruntime\"" --cfg "feature=\"inaddr\"" --cfg "feature=\"qos\"" --cfg "feature=\"basetsd\"" --cfg "feature=\"propidl\"" --cfg "feature=\"windef\"" --cfg "feature=\"reason\"" --cfg "feature=\"winreg\"" --cfg "feature=\"ktmtypes\"" --cfg "feature=\"ntstatus\"" --cfg "feature=\"guiddef\"" --cfg "feature=\"wincontypes\"" --cfg "feature=\"rpc\"" --cfg "feature=\"cfgmgr32\"" --cfg "feature=\"objidlbase\"" (exit code: 0xc0000409, STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN)
error: failed to compile soroban-cli v20.3.4, intermediate artifacts can be found at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-install0pJ2NA.
To reuse those artifacts with a future compilation, set the environment variable CARGO_TARGET_DIR to that path.
PS C:\Users\admin>

History restored

C:\Users\admin> soroban
soroban : The term 'soroban' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

soroban

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (soroban:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException




